# lazy evaluation and rspec's let method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am reading the book The Rails 4 Way, and I am learning about Rspec. I know that lazy evaluation is when the expression is not evaluated until it is used, whereas eager evaluation is where the expression is evaluated immediately. `let` uses lazy evaluation, where the expression in the block will not be executed until the let variable is used. And `let!` uses eager evaluation.

However, I am still a little confused about `let` and `let!` in rspec. Let's take the example below, from the book:

```
describe BlogPost do
  let(:blog_post) { BlogPost.create title: 'Hello' } 
  let!(:comment) { blog_post.comments.create text: 'first post' }

  describe "#comment" do 
    before do    
      blog_post.comment("finally got a first post") 
    end  

    it "adds the comment" do 
      expect(blog_post.comments.count).to eq(2)
    end 
  end
end
```

The author says the following:

> Since the comment block would never have been executed for the first
>   assertion if you used a let definition, only one comment would have
>   been added in this spec even though the implementation may be working.
>   By using let! we ensure the initial comment gets created and the spec
>   will now pass.

I thought that with let, there would be two comments created and with let!, there would be three comments created. Why? Because with let, the block would not be executed, so no comments created there. However, comment will be lazy evaluated in the before block, so now we have one comment. Then the comment block will be evaluated again in the "adds the comment" block so therefore two comments would be created. Since let! evaluates immediately, there would thus be 3 comments created, rather than just two.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing invocations of the lazy `comment` method where there are none.

> However, comment will be lazy evaluated in the before block

No, the before block you've show us has nothing to do with `let(:comment)`.

Using `blog_post.comment` is unrelated to Rspec, or `let`. It's using a method, `comment`, defined on your `BlogPost` model.

> Then the comment block will be evaluated again in the "adds the comment" block

Again, no, there is no invocation whatsoever of `comment` inside that block. The only thing that's even close is `blog_post.comments`, comment**s** plural, not comment, and that is accessing a `has_many` relationship on your model.

The only way to invoke the `comment` defined by `let(:comment)` is with **the word `comment`**. Methods that have same names but belong to different objects aren't relevant.

Comment: If there are no invocations of comment method as you said above, then why does the author say "if you used a let definition, only one comment would have been added in this spec even though the implementation may be working. By using let! we ensure the initial comment gets created and the spec will now pass (have 2 comments)"

Comment: @Donato Because you're still creating a comment, you're just not creating it via the lazy `comment` method. The `before` block **does** create a comment, but it has nothing to do with "... comment will be lazy evaluated". At no point, anywhere in the code shown, will `comment` be lazily evaluated; that is the author's point. That is why you need `let!`

Comment: @meager where else is a comment being created? I only see creation in the block of the let method. No where else.

Comment: @Donato Yes, there is one comment created in the before block. But it has nothing to do with `let(:comment)`.